# How to do SSO login with Intune SDK integrated Android Apps

Tags: android, android-studio, adal, intune

I am trying to do SSO login in Android app but getting exception:

> I/AuthManager: Exception : The base64 url encoded signature component of the redirect uri does not match the expected value. Type: com.microsoft.aad.adal.cl

Using Intune SDK and ADAL lib to build intune SDK integrated native Android app and It works fine if we login to app without SSO. Now trying to implement SSO login as Microsoft document says in below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-v1-enable-sso-android. But it doesn't work and getting exception as above.

We have already configured redirect URI in Azure portal based on Base64UrlencodedSignature.

Set as broker app :

```
AuthenticationSettings.INSTANCE.setUseBroker(true);
```

Trying to signin with prompt :

```
AuthManager.signInWithPrompt(mAuthContext, StartActivity.this,
                        StartActivity.this, PromptBehavior.Auto, mHandler);
```

I am using Taskr sample application as a test application which link given below:
https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/Taskr-Sample-Intune-Android-App

Comment: "I can provide code snippet if required" - that is probably a good idea. Please edit your question, and use the formatting tools provided. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer Thanks for comment, i went through the link you shared and i will keep in mind the same from next time. and edited question as well.

Comment: There is no need to add offers to add extra code to questions - readers know to ask for more information. In six months/years time, when this question is no longer important to you, readers want to see a succinct question with no distracting conversational material.